Google blogspot api PERMISSION_DENIED, what is missing?
I have created credentials on google developer console:

one API key and assigned blogspot API to the key
one oauth client (consent screen configured)

The oauth client is in test mode (not verified yet), but added some test emails.
I could successfully retrieve an access token with authorization code grant flow, using an authorization url that looks like this (client id, redirect_uri changed):
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=1234&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%example.com%3A4430%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fblogger&state=abcd1234&prompt=consent
Most importantly:

scopes = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger
prompt=consent

I get this from the token endpoint:
{
  "access_token": "***",
  "refresh_token": "****",
  "expires_in": 3108,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger openid",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "id_token": "***"
}

It seems that the blogger scope is assigned to the token.
Next, I try to POST to https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs//posts?key=<MY_APPLICATION_KEY> as it is documented here https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost and I get this response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Most importantly:

the MY_APPLICATION_KEY matches my test application's key
BLOGID belongs to a blog that is owned by the authenticated user
the same authenticated user owns the (test) application
the same authenticated user's email address is added as a test user to the application
the blogspot api was enable on the application key

What am I missing?
Also, it is not clear to me who "the caller" is. Is it the application, or is it the authorized user? Or both? Anyway, if I try the same call without the key parameter then I get a different error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

